# How to copy files from Android root directory app to SDCard or PC (Rooted Device)

Tags: applications, root-access

I have an app which allows downloading videos too but it can be viewed only via app.
Now I've rooted my tablet but still unable to copy those videos from Root Directory App Data to SDCard or My computer using Total Commander.
Tried several method to pull app package from adb as well but no luck.

Files location: Data/data/com.app.package/app_files
Videos permission in the directory shows rw----- and when I do it from Root File Manager in my device, it crashes. When I try doing the same from Total Commander, it says Error Downloading file!

Commands I've executed on adb:

> adb pull "/data/data/com.app.package/" Z:\Data
>
> Result: Cannot find 'Data.....'
>
> adb shell run-as com.app.package cp /data/data/com.app.package/
>
> Result: run-as: Package 'com.app.package' is not debuggable

Comment: What's that app? Where does it save files? Are you sure files aren't encrypted? Please elaborate ***"but still unable to copy those videos"***. How pulling app package is related to copying video files? What do you exactly mean by saying ***"Root Directory"***? Apps don't save files to root directory (`/`).

Comment: Sorry if I am not able to convey my problem properly, I'm a newbie with root access and all. There's this app which provide educational videos to be downloaded offline and it saves the video in m4v format in data/data/com.app.package/app_files and I'm unable to copy those videos from there to SDCard or My Computer.

Comment: *"unable to copy"* isn't clear. What's the error you get when trying to copy?

Comment: Videos permission in the directory shows rw----- and when I do it from Root File Manager in my device, it crashes. When I try doing the same from Total Commander, it says Error Downloading file!

Comment: Include this last comment and the files location in your question (by editing) to get better response. Though there is not obvious reason. May be SELinux. Better use commandline tools for copying to get more precise reason of failure.

Comment: @iWhiteSharK Please edit your question and include all commands you have executed and for the command that fails the complete error message.

Comment: have you tried `adb backup com.app.package` (leave password blank) or `adb exec-out su -c "tar -c data/data/com.app.package" > com.app.package.tar`